# Deleting map elements in a range-based loop

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-ranges, range-based-loop

I would like to drop a number of elements from a map based on some condition:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<int, int> numbers = {{1,2}, {2,1}, {3,2}, {4,5}};

    auto even = [](auto entry){return entry.second %2 == 0;};
    for(auto& [key, val] : numbers | std::views::filter(even)) {
        numbers.erase(val);
    }

    for(auto& [key, val] : numbers) {
        std::cout << key << " " << val << "\n";
    }
}
```

But it seems there I am invalidating iterators that the range-based loop needs:

```
4 5
3 2
1 2
```

I know how to do this explicitly using iterators, but is there a nice and concise range-based way to delete elements based on a filter?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase_if), like below:

```cpp
std::erase_if(numbers, [](auto entry) {return entry.second % 2 == 0; });
```

If you want a ranges solution, and you do not need in-place changing, you can do something like below (this code compiles only in C++23):

```cpp
numbers = numbers | std::views::filter(even) | std::ranges::to<decltype(numbers)>();
```

I am not sure, but maybe the below code is better performance than normal ranges code as above, based on documentation:

```cpp
auto temp_numbers = numbers | std::views::filter(even) | std::ranges::to<decltype(numbers)>();
numbers.swap(temp_numbers);
```

As you can see in the [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator%3D) for `std::unordered_map`, the complexity of its move assignment operator is **linear**, but the complexity of its [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) is **constant**, and the complexity of its [`swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/swap) method is **constant**, so it seems to be better performance. But, I do not have any benchmark for this.

Comment: `numbers=std::move(...);` might be better than `swap`.

Comment: @Red.Wave as I surprise, the documentation says, move constructor, has **linear** complexity, instead of **constant`, so I have to use `swap`, did you have any idea, why?

Comment: @sorosh_sabz, No. The linear time complexity belongs to allocator-using overload. The move constructor runs in constant-time.

Comment: @Red.Wave I do not speak about move constructor, I speak about move assignment, `numbers=std::move(...);` calls move assignment, not move constructor, and move assignment as you can see in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator%3D, has linear complexity, independent of allocator type.